# crontab listing or editing results in fopen: permission denied

Tags: cron, ubuntu-10.10, permissions

Recently, a job configured to run from a user's crontab stopped executing. When attempting to list or edit the crontab for the user, the result is:

```
user@host:~$ crontab -l
crontabs/user/: fopen: Permission denied

user@host:~$ crontab -e
crontabs/user/: fdopen: Permission denied
```

Clearly it is permissions related, though I'm not sure how the permissions got changed -- and more importantly, what they should be set to.

Permissions on /usr/bin/crontab:

```
$ ll /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root libuuid 35896 Aug 24  2010 /usr/bin/crontab*
```

Permissions on /var/spool/cron/crontab directory:

```
# ll /var/spool/cron/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Oct 12  2010 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    4096 Jun  5 20:51 ../
drwx-wx--T 2 root libuuid 4096 Jan 10  2014 crontabs/
```

Permissions inside crontab directory:

```
# ll /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
total 16
drwx-wx--T 2 root libuuid 4096 Jan 10  2014 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Oct 12  2010 ../
-rw------- 1 1017 libuuid 1120 Dec  3  2013 
-rw------- 1 root libuuid 1342 Jan 10  2014 root
```

Distro info:

```
# cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might want to look into upgrading. Security updates are a good thing.

Comment: Who is user ? 2013 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The permissions on /usr/bin/crontab should be:

```
 owner=root
 group=root
 perms= 4755  (rws rx rx)
```

Your /usr/bin/crontab has the wrong group owner.  Additionally, it has sgid and NOT suid which it must have.

Comment: Is there any reason why the defaults wouldn't be what you wrote? I haven't touched my permissions (Ubuntu 14.04), and I have `-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 35984 Feb  9  2013 /usr/bin/crontab`.

Comment: I ran into this issue after deleting a recreating a user with a different UID - this fixed it for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/710671/cannot-access-crontab-after-changing-uid

Answer (score 7):

You can edit your user crontab if you have superuser access, without modifying permissions:

```
$ sudo crontab -u username -e
```

I thought you could edit your user crontab without sudo, but I get the same permission issues as you, even after adding myself to the `crontab` group. The permissions in my user's crontab (`/var/spool/cron/crontabs`) are `-rw-------`, group is `crontab`.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error. The issue was on directory `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

```
$ sudo stat /var/spool/cron/crontabs
  Fichier : '/var/spool/cron/crontabs'
   Taille : 34          Blocs : 0          Blocs d'E/S : 4096   répertoire
Périphérique : 802h/2050d   Inœud : 272986341   Liens : 2
Accès : (1730/drwx-wx--T)  UID : (    0/    root)   GID : (  107/ crontab)
Accès : 2020-07-10 14:01:01.246597775 +0200
Modif. : 2020-07-10 14:01:00.806605868 +0200
Changt : 2020-07-10 14:01:00.806605868 +0200
  Créé : -
```

If you have different permission / owner / group, you can fix it like this :

```
sudo chmod 1730 /var/spool/cron/crontabs
sudo chown root:crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```