# User crontab not accessible

Tags: permissions, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I cannot edit my user crontab without being superuser.

I expected the following to work, but I get an error message:

```
$ crontab -e
crontabs/gauthier/: fdopen: Permission denied
```

The following is working, but I don't think I should need sudo to edit my user-specific crontab:

```
$ sudo crontab -u gauthier -e
```

The permissions on my user crontab:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs
total 4
-rw------- 1 1001 crontab 1139 Sep 10 08:36 gauthier
```

I tried adding myself to the crontab group, to no av (I understand now that I shouldn't be in that group, it's only for SGID to work).

An answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/619296/crontab-listing-or-editing-results-in-fopen-permission-denied/647743#647743) says to change the permissions, owner, and group of `/usr/bin/crontab`, but that file does not seem involved here. And I don't see why these permissions would have changed from system defaults.

Where am I wrong? Is it normal that `crontab -e` doesn't work? Even if I am in the `crontab` group? What should I do instead? If I need to change the permissions and owner of `/usr/bin/crontab`, why aren't they working in the default installation?

Comment: What are the permissions on /usr/bin/crontab ? I know you referenced a post about this but your symptoms sound like it isn't setuid root. Let's just eliminate this. Should be ... nph9@goat$ ls -l /usr/bin/crontab
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 51784 Nov 23  2013 /usr/bin/crontab
nph9@goat$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission for your crontab is wrong, it is owned by an (nonexistant?) user with the `uid` 1001, not the user `gauthier` (or you have some further issues with your system if your `uid` is 1001).

Try `sudo chown gauthier /var/spool/cron/crontabs/gauthier` and see if this fixes this.

Comment: Correct! I recall changing my uid from 1001 to 1000 long ago, it never seemed a good idea but it gave some promises with another issue. I got it confirmed: it was not a good idea :) Thanks !